# Alfresco + Selenium WebDriver. Wait for AJAX

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm developing tests with TestNG and Selenium WebDriver for some custom Alfresco modules being developed by our team.

After the page loading I need to wait for all AJAX requests to get necessary WebElement.
I found [this approach](http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/selenium-wait-for-ajax-the-right-way/). I've [figured out](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/AJAX_Support) that Alfresco uses Dojo.

So i wrote a following method (timeout is yet to be added):

`void waitForAJAX() {`

```
if(javascriptExecutor == null) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(webDriverType.toString() + " does not support javascript execution.");
}
boolean presentActiveConnections = true;
Integer numOfCon;
// Minor optimization. Getting rid of the repeaedly invocation of valueOf() in while.
Integer zeroInteger = Integer.valueOf(0);
while(presentActiveConnections) {
    numOfCon = (Integer)javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().dojo.io.XMLHTTPTransport.inFlight.length");
    if( numOfCon.equals(zeroInteger) ) {
        presentActiveConnections = false;
    }
}
```

`}`

But when i run my tests i get following error on invocation of this method from the test:

> Failed: ReferenceError: dojo is not defined.

Should dojo variable be available from any javascript? I was unable to locate it too when i manually checked the page source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to test? Is this in Alfresco Share, Explorer or some other web client? The old WCM forms used to use Dojo, and it has been the focus of some recent bleeding edge stuff, but pretty much all of Share uses YUI2.

Comment: It is in Alfresco Share, sorry, i forgot to mention that. So i need to find out how to get number of active connections in YUI?

I've googled [this](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=22154) so i looks like there is no ready solution in YUI to find out the number of active AJAX connections.

So if there isn't some request queue in Alfresco pages javascript made by it's developers i have nothing to do with this? How can i figure out is there such a queue?

Comment: The link in your last comment is a YUI3 resource. Share uses YUI2. But anyway, why do you need to wait for the AJAX requests to complete, vs. say, using `onContentReady` or `addListener` (making use of handler attachment deferral) from [YAHOO.util.Event](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/) to detect when your content is available?

Comment: Actually I see that forum post does reference YUI2, but anyway there is no such queue on `Alfresco.util.Ajax`, which is the helper class in Share. So my question above still stands.

Comment: Alfresco.util.Ajax uses YUI2 YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/connection/index.html. Did you open up the share/js/alfresco.js file and look up Alfresco.util.Ajax definition? Maybe you'll find interesting stuff there. Or dragons :)

Comment: Also, is there something extra in your custom component that you can hook on?

Comment: Hmm. Apparently, Alfresco.util.Ajax puts something on the Window object: " // Use setTimeout to execute the script. Note scope will always be "window"/ var scripts = result[1]; / if (...) { window.setTimeout(scripts, 0)...  You can wait for that?